VS2022 losing code changes after closing solution
Recently any changes I make to a solution vanish after closing Visual Studio. I'm using Git as the repo.
For example, I add 3 new files, write code, save, build, run, debug. All my files are saved locally as expected. But if I close Visual Studio and re-open it, All my changes are lost and the files are missing.
I've been using Visual Studio for 23 years and I have never had this happen before.
Has anyone else experienced this, or know what could be causing this because it is really frustrating.
Just to be sure it is not some strange interaction between VS2022 and Git, I have zipped my code changes, and removed the network cable, and then closed Visual Studio. The zip file contains all my changes.
I open the solution again in Visual Studio, and all my changes have vanished, so I unzip my backup and confirm all the files are now visible in Visual Studio.
I click 'Save All' and close Visual Studio.
I then open Visual Studio again, and all my changes have vanished yet again.

yes this is abnormal and could be beyond the VS2022 or Git issue as i am using 2022 VS also and never experience it. Did you ever run chkdsk on the disk, maybe some disk issues loosing changes and not saving properly. File system might be corrupted.

I'd suggest put the files into a new clean project and start again in a fresh directory. I wouldn't like to develop in an environment where things can just vanish like that. I've not seen that particular behaviour but I have seen quite a few oddities in my time. Creating a fresh clean project and incorporating all the source code files  into it usually fixes things. I have never bothered to investigate it any deeper than that.

I have also used VS to do similar work, but never encountered the problem you described. I think you can check the following places: simply check whether there is any synchronization software that interferes with the file saving; reinstall VS to see if the problem is improved; or, as Martin suggested, create a new clean project and import the source code file into the new project to see if the problem is solved.
